# dojox/widget/Toaster to show latest one first

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using dojox/widget/Toaster to show the toaster message,
I have declared it as,

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/widget/Toaster" id="toast2"
                        data-dojo-props='positionDirection:"br-up", messageTopic:"/app/notif", duration:"8000"'>
                                </div>
```

And im calling from javascript from different places as,

```
connect.publish('/app/notif', [ "<b><font color=\"red\">"+ "Toaster Message" +". </font></b>" ]);
```

But im able to see the latest message on the bottom of toaster,

I need it to be at the top, can you suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `tr-down` instead of `br-up` for property `positionDirection`.

Options for `positionDirection` from which message slides into screen are:

["br-up", "br-left", "bl-up", "bl-right", "tr-down", "tr-left", "tl-down", "tl-right"]

If your issue persists, please consider disable any custom CSS on your Toaster if any, for debug porpoises.

API documentation for Toaster:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/widget/Toaster

Comment: tr-down makes the toaster to show on the top right of the screen.
For me the position should be br-up but the latest message should come first.
Ex:
3 message,
2 message,
1 message
instead of ,
1 message
2 message
3 message

Comment: Please use this https://jsfiddle.net/g05nkofe/ to reproduce your issue, I will try to fix it for you :). Let me know thanks!